# What does $\mathbb{C} / \mathbb{Z}$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

In the following question I need to use $\mathbb{C} / \mathbb{Z}$ :

Prove that $\mathbb{C} / \mathbb{Z}$  is isomorphic to the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{C}^*,\cdot, 1)$.

But what does $\mathbb{C} / \mathbb{Z}$  mean? I understand things like $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$, but cannot grasp $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}$ . Thanks!

Comment: An intermediate example might be $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, which has a snappy geometric meaning. Then you can think of $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}$ as "that, but $\times$ a line (= the imaginary axis)" - and again you'll see a nice "shape" being described.

Comment: What's the difference between $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ that you can't grasp?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^*$ does not contain purely integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of the additive group of $\mathbb{C}$, so you can take the quotient $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb C/\mathbb Z$ is a cylinder.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ under addition has no inherent topological or geometric structure, so this is not really inherent to the construction. But it's probably a good way to visualize it.

Comment: @6005: I think the same remark can hold to $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$... :)

Comment: Indeed, $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ has no inherent topological or geometric structure :)